# python - run subprocess command with single quote

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to run the following command in python.  It finds the duration of files in a directory. But i have a syntax error that i'm unsure how to address.

```
find /Volumes/Storage/test. -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.mp4' -exec ffprobe -v quiet -of csv=p=0 -show_entries format=duration {} \; | paste -sd+ -| bc
```

Python code:

```
import subprocess

cmd = "/Volumes/Storage/test. -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.mp4' -exec ffprobe -v quiet -of csv=p=0 -show_entries format=duration {} \; | paste -sd+ -| bc"
result2 = subprocess.run(['find', '/Volumes/Storage/test. -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.mkv' -exec ffprobe -v quiet -of csv=p=0 -show_entries format=duration {} \; | paste -sd+ -| bcmd'])
print (result2)
```

I get this error:

```
 File "/Volumes/Storage/command2.py", line 4
    result2 = subprocess.run(['find', '/Volumes/Storage/test. -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.mp4' -exec ffprobe -v quiet -of csv=p=0 -show_entries format=duration {} \; | paste -sd+ -| bcmd'])
                                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I suspect it's the single quote.  How do you use the subprocess with a single quote inside?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape quotes

```py
# escaped
'random string \'quote\' close string'

# not escaped
'random string 'quote' close string'
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see already from syntax highlighting, the single quote that is part of the command is terminating your string that you also enclosed in single quotes. A very easy fix is to simply use double quotes for the string, i.e

```py
result2 = subprocess.run(["find", "/Volumes/Storage/test. -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.mp4' -exec ffprobe -v quiet -of csv=p=0 -show_entries format=duration {} \; | paste -sd+ -| bcmd"])
```

The other way would be to escape the quotes with a backslash `' \' '` (which is a string that contains a single quote)